# do not call onLocationChanged if not moved more than 10 meters

Tags: android, google-maps, location

Is there a way to restrict the call to onLocationChanged if user has not moved 10 meters or more.

I am using google map with map fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize location manager with parameter minimum distance to 10 and minimum time to 0 .

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/

Comment: i am using the same but still when i connect using home wifi my location keep changing locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 10, this);

Comment: If you use ACCURACY_FINE, you will use GPS only, but GPS have "cold start" effect. It means that if you device not used GPS long time, it needs a lot of time for connecting with satellites and download almanac and ephemeris. You can't change this behavior.

If you don't use ACCURACY_FINE, you will use both GPS and network (mobile, wi-fi) signals. So you will receive quick first position from network, because they don't have "cold start" effect, but accuracy of this method is low. When your GPS module will ready, you will start receive updates from it too.

Comment: i am not using ACCURACY_FINE , I am using  Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);

Comment: Use ACCURACY_FINE in your case because your WIFI location changing

Comment: I made the changes as you said,will test and let you know . Thanks for the help

Comment: I have tested the application with ACCURACY_FINE and still my location keep updating

Answer (score 0):

Use Google fuesed location api for location updates.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java

And for distance use LocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement() method. For that - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#public-methods